# Storing output of with_items into single variable in ansible

Tags: ansible

Is there any way to store the output of all the output of with_items into a single variable. The reason I am asking is because, I need to check the uptime of few servers before and after taking some action. List is stored in /etc/hosts/

```
- hosts: hosts
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
      - name: Genrate the node list
        shell: "for node in $(awk '{print $1}' /etc/hosts"
        register: node_list
        become: true


      - name: get the uptime of all nodes
        shell:  "ssh {{ item }} \"awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime\""
        with_items:
          - "{{ node_list.stdout_lines }}"
        become: true
```

Question is how to store all the output of "name: get the uptime of all nodes" into a single variable , so that I can compare it before and after taking action.

As a temp solution, I have redirected the output of awk command into a NFS directory which is shared between local and remote_server and later did comparison locally using another awk. This works fine but I have to loop twice and store files which call for cleanup.

Comment: Please share what have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is to move the looped task into an include file, which also contains a task to update a fact composed of either a list or dictionary, with the output from your command, and then attach the loop to the include task:

include_file.yml:

```
---
- name: get the uptime of a node
    shell:  "ssh {{ item }} \"awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime\""
  register: host_uptime
  become: true
- set_fact:
    hosts_uptime: "{{ hosts_uptime | default({}) | combine({ item: host_uptime.stdout}) }}
```

and in your playbook:

```
- name: get hosts uptime
  include: include_file.yml
  loop: "{{ node_list.stdout_lines }}"
- debug:
    var: hosts_uptime
```

As an aside, if all the hosts that you wish to get the uptime for were part of your Ansible inventory, as long as you had gathered facts from them first, you would be able to access the uptime data with `hostvars['some_hostname']['ansible_uptime_seconds']` rather than have to have that adhoc SSH command.